# PHP json_decode - how to use with escape quotes string?

Tags: php, json

I have this string:

```
{\"sub\":\"value\"}
```

How I can use json_decode on this string?
When I try do it in that way:

```
$text = '{\"sub\":\"value\"}';
$json = json_decode($text, true);
var_dump($json);
```

I got `NULL` as result.

I know, I can use something like that:

```
$text = str_replace('\"', '"', $text);
```

But it also return null, because my original string is more extensive.

Real json_string you can found here: https://www.olx.pl/oferta/praca/praca-w-sklepie-internetowym-CID4-IDP2Wy2.html
It start from: `window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__= "` and end at the end of this code line.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your json seems poorly encoded at first, what adds slashes to your double quotes in the json to decode? - Your link point to a website, not a json ressource

Comment: Use double quotes and PHP will unescape it. That said, copy/pasting random data between different language's source files is going to be a total crapshoot.

Comment: @SNS-WebetInformatique open this url, click CTRL + U (check HTML source of opened website), then found part of string: `window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__= "` - all found line is json code which I want to use into json_decode function.

Comment: @Sammitch, can you give an example?

Comment: ok i see the json integrated in the html page, -> it's ugly! But when i enter this in the console: window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__
it return "undefined" ... may be post the entire code of this json string

Comment: `json_decode(stripslashes($text, true));` unless there is escaped stuff inside the text.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP: Strings - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) escape sequences will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings

That means your string `$text = '{\"sub\":\"value\"}';` will be treated as string with separate `\` and `"` characters, which is invalid JSON string.

You need to use double quotes around string `$text = "{\"sub\":\"value\"}";` in that case `\"` will be expanded, therefore you will get a valid JSON string.